# Create React App with Node / Express import images

Tags: express, create-react-app, imagesource

I'm fairly new to this and taken a look through various forums. I'm trying to find the best way.

I've followed a tutorial that gives you the `create-react-app` boiler plate work with a node express backend. All this is working fine, where the React boiler plate is under a folder named "site" within my Node application. I then use a proxy in `package.json` to direct all traffic to my API... all of this seems fairly standard as there are plenty of tutorials around for this.

The trouble I have now is that I have dynamically added images and saved their paths to database. But when I pull these out as static images to be used within my React app it naturally can not find the images. All within (`./public/images`) of my node application.

I was looking for the best advice really or the best practice way of serving these images to my React frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to serve static files like images from `./public/images`, you need to use the Express built-in static method in a middleware :

```
  // Top level middleware : serve static files method
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/images"));
```

You can client access your ressources :

```
  http://localhost:8080/my.png
```

More about [express.static();](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static) method